# Code failing while converting csv file to XML format in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert CSV file to XML format .

I am trying to do insert current date in `CREDTM` field in XML.

**My code**

```
header =""""
<ilsord:IRD
    xmlns:plnk="http://deft.dnt.nn/com/plnk/0100"
    xmlns:func="http://dft/func">
    <hdr:MSGHDR>
        <REC types:ADRTYP="CU">
            <PHYREC>OFS</PHYREC>
            <LOGREC>USDRD08</LOGREC>
        </REC>
        <PHYSND>IB</PHYSND>
        <SNDAPP>OFS</SNDAPP>
        <MSGTYP>ILSORD</MSGTYP>
        <VERNUM>0100</VERNUM>
        <CREDTM>{0}</CREDTM>
    </hdr:MSGHDR>
    """

from datetime import datetime
import time
df = pd.read_csv('XML.csv')
glogdate = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')


with open('Mont.xlm', 'w') as f:
    f.write(header.format(glogdate))
```

**Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-221-9da75a1ec2a1> in <module>
      6 
      7 with open('Mont.xlm', 'w') as f:
----> 8     f.write(header.format(glogdate))

/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'format'
```

How to fix this issue

Comment: The error says that `header` is a DataFrame, and not the template string you displayed here... Are you sure you don't have a `header = pd.read_csv(...)` line or similar you're not showing here?

Comment: yes my header and dataframe are different.

Comment: Try `type(header)` in your ipython prompt? Or just `header`...

Comment: its coming as `str`

Comment: Can you still reproduce the issue? That's what the error message is saying, it's complaining that `DataFrame` doesn't have a `.format()` method, and you're calling that on `header`...

Comment: @filbranden, I just fixed the  issue. I was just white space intentation issue.Sorry for the troublr

Comment: No trouble! Glad you found the issue.